# chown user directories, no user exists

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, chown

the problem that I am having is that I am unable to chmod user directories so the users have control over their own directories.  When the Ubuntu server was setup, one user, patrick, assumed full control as seen in the image.  I want to change this so every user has control of their own directory like some of the directories have.  using chmod, I get an error that says the user does not exist.  I get the same error when I use the id command.  Thanks for helping, and happy Valentines day!
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems that those users does not exist in your system. Check this with something like:

```
$ getent passwd | grep celik
```

The user exists if there's output from the above command. I'm giving you this command instead of 'id' you tried because i'm not sure id uses nss passwd database resolution (id is not linked to libnss in my system), and maybe you've got those users via LDAP, for example.

If they do not exists you have to recreate them. You can find users to recreate with something like:

```
$ find /home -maxdepth 1 -type d -user patrick -exec basename {} \; | grep -v patrick
```

Then use 'useradd' to add all of them. Make sure you use the '-M' option (do not create homedir). After creation use 'chmod -R' to change user/group ownership recursively.